# object destructing from mongodb with undefined length

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nodemailer, express-handlebars, object-destructuring

`enter code here`I have a created a shoppingCart app  and I have to send the order to the client in email using nodemailer I cannot destructure this object

this object can have many similar values like this

```
{"5e4083f2c3231acf1ded8b1f":
{"item":
{
  "_id":"5e4083f2c3231acf1ded8b1f",
  "imagePath":"https://ahn9mtnal7pbz2v5wyw2gqon.drv.tw/ait.jpeg",
  "title":"My img",
  "description":"lambi cjhori decstkjfnsjknf fhfhf time nhi hai",
  "price":100},
  "qty":1,"price":100,"singlePrice":100}}
```

I have tried

```
let iofi = JSON.stringify(cart.items);

console.log("  iofi = stringify cart.items : "+ iofi );

let cartItemsvalues = Object.values(cart.items);

console.log("CV",cartItemsvalues);
```

and only `${iofi}` works in `nodemailer` Html: output

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to send title,desc,price only in the email instead of the whole object

Comment: So this is a javascript question then? Why is it tagged mongodb?

Comment: because object is coming from mongodb database

Comment: That is immaterial to your question/problem.